# Install yum in CentOS without make

Tags: linux, centos, wget, yum, make

I'm working with GoDaddy via SSH, and I noticed that the OS (CentOS 5.8) doesn't have `yum`.  It does seem to have `wget` and `rpm`, but it doesn't have `make`, so I ran into a wall when trying to install `yum` after grabbing it with `wget`. I haven't used CentOS much at all, and I've done quite a bit of googling with no success. Hopefully someone here can help out, thanks!

Comment: Does https://www.net24.co.nz/kb/article/AA-00253 help?  I realise that 5.8 is not in the list, but maybe you can tweak e.g. the version 5.7 one from the list to match your needs?

Comment: Thanks, I found the correct packages [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/); however, it won't end up working for me (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Download yum RPM package from public repositories, like: [here](http://fr.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=yum&submit=Search%20...)

```
# wget /URL/to/repo/yum-VERSION.rpm
```

Try to install it:

```
# rpm -ivh yum-VERSION.rpm
```

It will require dependencies (6-8 RPMs).
You can get them in the same repositories.

Answer (score 0):

After calling GoDaddy for the second time yesterday, I finally found out that we're on a shared hosting plan (which I suspected but was unsure of, since I didn't handle setup and didn't look into it), so I can't get root access--which basically means no installing anything. I was told that their other plans (such as those granting a virtual private server) come with `yum` installed.

If you actually were in a situation where you had `rpm` but not `yum`, you should be able to grab the packages [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/) for CentOS 5.8 (you can find others by starting [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/)--or back another directory). You should then be able to do something like `rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-40.el5.centos.noarch.rpm`
 and so on to install the required packages.